# Porting a servlet to a web service - accessing the context?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, axis

Consider a simply servlet:

```
// MyServlet.java
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    UtilClass.doSomething(getServletContext().getRealPath(SOME_FILE));
}
```

And the utility class does something with the file:

```
// UtilClass.java
public String doSomething(String filePath)
{
    File f = new File(filePath);
    String s = readWhateverFrom(f);
    return s;
}
```

I am now porting the `doSomething()` function to a web service running under Tomcat and **Axis2**. How would I port it so that I can still access the context and get access to a file under the servlet?

Comment: I can't give the exact answer as I don't do Axis, but I can at least tell that you really shouldn't pass the `ServletContext` outside the, uhm, servlet context. If you can, rather pass the filepath (or maybe a `File` or `InputStream`) to the webservice.

Comment: A `File` is not a valid parameter for a web service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get ahold of your (jax-ws) `MessageContext`. This would depend on your configuration, but perhaps using

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext wsCtx;
```

and in your method:

```
MessageContext messageContext = wsCtx.getMessageContext()

ServletContext ctx = (ServletContext) 
           messageContext.getProperty(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);
```

Edit: Seems like Axis2 (as well as Axis) support the following:

```
HttpServlet servlet = (HttpServlet) 
    MessageContext.getCurrentContext().getProperty(HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_SERVLET);
ServletContext ctx = servlet.getServletContext();
```

With the following imports:

```
import org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext;
import org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants;
```

Comment: sounds like a good idea - but I'm getting a null `wsCtx`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for a Servlet `Filter` and a `ThreadLocal`. Axis is running within a Servlet Context, too. So all you have to do is to implement a custom `javax.servlet.Filter`, stuffing in the `ServletRequest` into a `ThreadLocal` where you can access it from within your utility class. You can get the `ServletContext` from the `FilterConfig`.

Comment: I assume that SOME_FILE is part of the web-service internals, not part of the business parameters.

Comment: that solution would work, but it is already implemented by the web service stack.

Comment: The problem with using either ServletContext or WebServiceContext directly is that you will have a dependency on them within your utility class - which you sure don't want to have. Stuffing in such information in your own ThreadLocal and let filters/listeners do that is more clean from a dep-mgmt point of view. But you're right, if it's already there, use it and don't reinvent the wheel :-)